# Any optimization on the script to create view and table based on a delta lake column

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

below scripts checks and create a delta lake view partitioning the data based on a column and also add a group to each view. Is there any further simplification or optimization can be done to below query to make it more faster. currently it takes lot of time to complete the job.

```
# To check and crete view and group based on Project Name

target_database = "main.deltalake_db"
distinctprojects = spark.sql("SELECT DISTINCT requestProjectUrlName FROM main.deltalake_db.Customers_Log_Table_test")

for project in distinctprojects.collect():
    project_name = project['requestProjectUrlName']
    if project_name is not None:
        view_name = f"view_{project_name.replace(' ', '_').replace('-', '_')}"
    groupname = f"users_{view_name}"
    
    # Check if group already exists
    group_exists = False
    for group in spark.sql("SHOW GROUPS").collect():
        if 'name' in group:
            group_name = group['name']
        else:
            group_name = group['groupName']
        if group_name == groupname:
            group_exists = True
            print(f"Group {groupname} already exists.")
            break
    
    if not group_exists:
        create_group = f"""
        CREATE GROUP {groupname} with USER `xxx@cdx.com`
        """
        try: 
            spark.sql(create_group)            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error creating group {groupname}: {e}")
        else:
            print(f"Group {groupname} created successfully.")
    
    # Check if view already exists
    view_exists = False
    for table in spark.catalog.listTables(target_database):
        if table.name == view_name:
            view_exists = True
            print(f"View {view_name} already exists.")
            break
    
    if not view_exists:
        create_view_query = f"""
        CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {target_database}.{view_name} AS
        SELECT * FROM {target_database}.Customers_Log_Table
        WHERE 
          CASE
            WHEN is_member('{groupname}') AND requestProjectUrlName = '{project_name}' THEN TRUE 
            ELSE FALSE
          END;
        """ 
        try: 
            spark.sql(create_view_query)
            
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error creating view {view_name}: {e}")
        else:
            print(f"View {view_name} created successfully.")
```